# How to load hibernate.cfg.xml file in the java standalone application

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I am writing java standalone application with hibernate annotations.I am placing "hibernate.cfg.xml" file inside src directory. During startup,I am creating session factory using

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

I am using ant build script to make compile and creating jar file.
When running my application, getting error

> "org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found"

Please let me know where to place this file and how to fix this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description place it in the folder above the `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you are placing  "hibernate.cfg.xml" file inside src directory ,then you can create create sessionFactory as shown below

```
  sessionFactory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory()
```